# String manipulation using Java regexp

Tags: java, regex

I have a String in this format:

```
mydb://<user>:<password>@<host>:27017
```

And I would like to use Java regexp in order to extract the `<user>` and `<password>` strings from the String. What would be the best way doing so?

EDIT:

I would like to be able to use this regexp in the String's replace method so that I'm left only with the relevant user and password Strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex (Pattern)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^mydb://([^:]+):([^@]+)@[^:]+:\\d+$");
```

And then capture group #1 and #2 will have your user and password respectively.

**Code:**

```
String str = "mydb://foo:bar@localhost:27017"; 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^mydb://([^:]+):([^@]+)@[^:]+:\\d+$");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println("User: " + matcher.group(1) + ", Password: "
                        + matcher.group(2));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
User: foo, Password: bar
```

**EDIT:** Based on your comments: if you want to use String methods then:

```
String regex = "^mydb://([^:]+):([^@]+)@[^:]+:\\d+$";
String user = str.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
String pass = str.replaceAll(regex, "$2")
```

Comment: thanks! Can I do this using one call to String replace method (see my EDIT above)?

Comment: You'll need to call String#replaceAll twice for user and password separately.

Comment: I believe when using replace the regexp has to be changed a bit as we need to replace what we don't want with "" instead of extracting the user and the passwpord?